# I want to make DFS with adjacent matrix to have ability on DFS with adjacent List

Tags: c, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Please let me know how to change the performance from O(n^2) to O(n+e) by inserting any codes.. without modification

```
typedef struct GraphType 
{ 
    int n; //the number of vertex GraphNode
    int adj_mat[50][50]; 
} GraphType;

void dfs_mat(GraphType* g,int v)
{
   int w;
   visited[v] = TRUE; // Show Visits at Vertex v
   print("visit %d ->", v); print visited vertex
   for(w = 0; w<g->n; w++) // search adjacent vertex
      if(g->adj_mat[v][w] && !visited[w])
         dfs_mat(g,w); // restart from vertex w
}

void graph_init(GraphType *g)
{
   int r,c;
   g->n=0;
   for(r=0;r<50;r++)
      for(c=0;c<50;c++)
         g->adj_mat[r][c]=0;
}

void insert_vertex(GraphType *g,int v)
{
   if(((g->n)+1)>50){
      printf("error");
      return;
   }
g->n++;
}

void insert_edge(GraphType *g, int start, int end)
{
   if(start >= g->n || end >= g->n){
      printf("error");
      return;
   }
   g->adj_mat[start][end] = 1;
   g->adj_mat[end][start] = 1;
}

int main(void){
   int i;
   GraphType g;

   graph_init(&g);
   for(i=0;i<4;i++)
      insert_vertex(&g,i);
   insert_edge(&g,0,1);
   insert_edge(&g,1,0);
   insert_edge(&g,0,3);
   insert_edge(&g,3,0);
   insert_edge(&g,1,2);
   insert_edge(&g,2,1);
   insert_edge(&g,1,3);
   insert_edge(&g,3,1);
   insert_edge(&g,2,3);
   insert_edge(&g,3,2);
   dfs_mat(&g,0);
}
```

First, recursion occurs as much as the vertex number Because we need to check the edges.

The problem is when the program visited all vertices. Even though all vertices have already been visited, the rest of the iterative operations are executed. I think I must include conditions in the operation of the iteration sentence. but I don't know that.

Please save me.

Comment: How is `GraphType` defined?

Comment: typedef struct GraphNode { 
int vertex; 
struct GraphNode* link;
} GraphNode

typedef struct GraphType { 
int n; //the number of vertex GraphNode
GraphNode* adj_list[50];
} GraphType;

Comment: This is for adjacency list, can you edit the post and also include the structs for adjacency matrix?

Comment: Also, DFS should use a stack. Have you implemented a stack?

Comment: I'm sorry for being late.. and Thank you for giving me your help! I edited source codes

Comment: and I used the system stack for recursion rather than the stack I made.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a variable, say `visited_count` and set it to number of nodes. Decrement this variable on each visit operation. Check each time if `visited_count` is equal to zero and if yes, then break out of the loop. Check the lines with `////////////////// CHANGE` written in the comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


typedef struct GraphType 
{ 
    int n; //the number of vertex GraphNode
    int adj_mat[50][50]; 
} GraphType;

static bool visited[50] = {false};
static int visited_count;            ////////////////// CHANGE

void dfs_mat(GraphType* g,int v)
{
   int w;
   visited[v] = true; // Show Visits at Vertex v
   visited_count--;         ////////////////// CHANGE
   printf("=== visit %d ===\n", v); // print visited vertex
   for(w = 0; w<g->n && visited_count; w++) // search adjacent vertex        ////////////////// CHANGE
   {
       if (v != w)         ////////////////// CHANGE
       {
          printf("Processing node: %d, neighbor = %d\n", v, w);      ////////////////// CHANGE - added for debugging
          if(g->adj_mat[v][w] && !visited[w])
             dfs_mat(g,w); // restart from vertex w
       }
   }
}

void graph_init(GraphType *g)
{
   int r,c;
   g->n=0;
   for(r=0;r<50;r++)
      for(c=0;c<50;c++)
         g->adj_mat[r][c]=0;
}

void insert_vertex(GraphType *g,int v)
{
   if(((g->n)+1)>50){
      printf("error");
      return;
   }
g->n++;
}

void insert_edge(GraphType *g, int start, int end)
{
   if(start >= g->n || end >= g->n){
      printf("error");
      return;
   }
   g->adj_mat[start][end] = 1;
   g->adj_mat[end][start] = 1;
}

int main(void){
   int i;
   GraphType g;

   graph_init(&g);
   visited_count = 4;        ////////////////// CHANGE
   for(i=0;i<4;i++)
      insert_vertex(&g,i);
   insert_edge(&g,0,1);
   insert_edge(&g,1,0);
   insert_edge(&g,0,3);
   insert_edge(&g,3,0);
   insert_edge(&g,1,2);
   insert_edge(&g,2,1);
   insert_edge(&g,1,3);
   insert_edge(&g,3,1);
   insert_edge(&g,2,3);
   insert_edge(&g,3,2);
   dfs_mat(&g,0);
}
```

Comment: omg.. Thank you so much!! you're a genius.  I hope what you do goes well.

Comment: Do upvote if you found the answer useful. :-)